# Notepad++ Regex: Replace Text in Line with Capture from the Next Line

Tags: notepad++, regex

I've got some text that looks like this:

```
if ( != null)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsDeleted", acct.IsDeleted);
else
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsDeleted", DBNull.Value);
if ( != null)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MasterRecordId", acct.MasterRecordId);
else
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MasterRecordId", DBNull.Value);
if ( != null)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", acct.Name);
```

I would like to make it look like:

```
if (acct.IsDeleted != null)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsDeleted", acct.IsDeleted);
else
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsDeleted", DBNull.Value);
if (acct.MasterRecordId != null)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MasterRecordId", acct.MasterRecordId);
else
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MasterRecordId", DBNull.Value);
if (acct.Name != null)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", acct.Name);
```

So basically find `( != null)` and replace it with a value from the subsequent line `acct.<field>`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(if \()( != null\)\R.+?)(\w+\.\w+)(?=\);$)`
- Replace with: `$1$3$2$3`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(           # group 1
    if \(       # literally
)           # end group
(           #  group 2
    != null\)   # literally
    \R          # any kind of linebreak
    .+?         # 1 or more any character but newline
)           # end group
(           # group 3
    \w+         # 1 or more word character
    \.          # a dot
    \w+         # 1 or more word character
)           # end group
(?=\);$)    # positive lookahead make sure we have ");" at the end of line
```

**Screenshot (before):**
[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that got me super close! But, it looks like it's leaving off the acct.<field> in the last parameter of command.Parameters.AddWithValue command.

Comment: @B.Scar: Add `$3` at the end of replacement, see my edit.

Comment: Dang, I was so close. Thanks so much, and thanks for the syntax explanation!